# Contextual filter with group ID and group name

Tags: 8, group

I have a page view which is currently using a group id as a contextual filter. This is working. However, I am trying to achieve a 'friendly url', so the url should contain the group name, rather than the group id.

For example:

- [Current] /b/%groupId/test - contextual filter using group id
- [Ideal] /b/%groupName/test - contextual filter using group name

Alternatively, if this is not possible, then I would like to know if its possible to include the group name - as well as the group id, in a similar way to how Stackoverflow.com urls work, where there is an id, and human-friendly/seo url that contains the subject of the post. In this case, the group name can be ignored by drupal as it is only needed for SEO - and not for routing.

Comment: Please **edit** your question to explain what you mean by "*I cannot properly achieve it.*". I.e. to edd more details about what is actually  happening, and what you would want/expect to happen. E.g. by adding an example of one or more paths, and the views results you get by using these paths. Also, it might help to include an export of the view you have so far.